# ZMQ Context socket creation is MUCH slower on new computer

Tags: python, c++, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

This was originally seen in Python, but has since been replicated in C++. Here is the unit test that distills down and replicates the behavior on my new laptop. These are just local socket connections.

```
def test_zmq_publisher_duration(self):
    max_duration = 1.0
    t0 = time.time()
    socket = zmq.Context.instance().socket(zmq.PUB)
    duration = time.time() - t0
    print(socket)
    self.assertLess(duration, max_duration, msg="socket() took too long.")
```

On other computers, and on my old laptop, this runs in a *fraction* of a second. However, on my new laptop (beefy Dell Precision 7730) this takes about **44 seconds**. I get similar results when creating a zmq.SUB (subscriber) socket.

If I step down into the socket() call, the two statements which consume all the time are as follows:

```
zmq/sugar/context.py
   class Context
      def instance(cls, io_threads=1):
         ...
         cls._instance = cls(io_threads=io_threads)
         ...

      def socket(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
         ...
         s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
         ...
```

I am perplexed and baffled. Everything else on the laptop seems to be fine. Perhaps I have *pip installed* my dependent modules in some slightly different way? Could a previously installed zmq module versus pyzmq be causing problems? Perhaps it is something in the laptop setup from our IT department? I have tried running as administrator, running from within PyCharm, running from the command-line, and unplugging the network cable while running.

I am relatively new to Python and ZMQ, but we have been developing on this project for months with no performance issues. In production code, we have a MessageBroker class that contains most of the pub/sub architecture. The unit test above was created by simply pulling the first significant line of code out of our MessageBroker.Publisher constructor (which creates the socket). Even though the socket creation is SLOW on this computer, our application does still come up and run properly after the sockets get created. It just takes 7 minutes to start the application.

I suspect Ed's Law of Debugging: "The more bizarre the behavior, the more stupid the mistake."

Comment: I don't know if this can help you, but often very long delays in network-related stuff come from some non-essential network service down in the bowels of the library/network stack failing for timeout (and being retried multiple times) for some reason - say, some internal DNS query that should be instantaneous but hangs. Not saying that this is exactly the case, but that's the general direction where I'd investigate. If you are on Linux, try to run it under `strace`; on any platform, run your program under a native code debugger, stop it during the wait and see what it's doing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Matteo. PyCharm and pdb only let me debug to a certain depth in zmq/sugar/context. I'm looking into methods to let me debug deeper.

Comment: Indeed you should use gdb and see what's going on a lower level if you are on Linux, or some other native debugger (lldb on macOS IIRC and windbg/visual studio/cdb on Windows).

Comment: This is a windows box. I tried creating a C++ project in Visual Studio that uses a ZMQ library pulled from NuGet. It also exhibits the same delay. I don't have the ZMQ source files readily available for this particular library, but I can see the disassembly. Most of the times when I pause execution the call stack is: create_socket -> reaper_t -> mailbox_t -> signaler_t -> signaler_t.make_fdpair(uint64 *, uint64 *).

Comment: It is now working for both C++ and Python. I will try to find out from the IT folks if they pushed any changes to my machine and I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This was apparently a Windows 10 or Laptop firmware issue. Some updates got pushed by the IT department and things worked normally the next day. Here are the items that were installed per the Event Viewer:

- Installed KB4456655:  Servicing stack update for Windows 10, version 1803: September 11, 2018 (stability improvements)
- Installed KB4462930: Update for Adobe Flash Player
- Installed KB4100347: Intel microcode updates
- Installed KB4485449: Servicing stack update for Windows 10 v1803 - Feb. 12
- Installed KB4487017: (Same description as KB4485449)
- Installed KB4487038: Security update for Adobe Flash Player